# Haversine Formula works as Normal SQL but not in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, formula

I am using haversine formula to find distance between users. It works well as a normal mysql piece of code. But when use the same in a stored procedure it not working and throws 0.00 distances. I don't know why?

This is the working code:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE  if exists temp_tab;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tab(temp_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_fb_id bigint(20) unique,distance double(15,8) default NULL) CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT into temp_tab (user_fb_id, distance)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT user_fb_id, 
             6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS( 11.01684450 )) * SIN(RADIANS(`Latitude`)) + COS(RADIANS( 11.01684450 )) * COS(RADIANS(`Latitude`)) * COS(RADIANS(`Longitude`) - RADIANS( 76.95583210 ))) AS `distance` 
      FROM `user_login_log` 
      WHERE user_id <>'1831820984' 
      HAVING `distance` <= 50 
      ORDER BY `activity_at` DESC) as t1
GROUP BY user_fb_id;

SELECT * FROM temp_tab;
```

Normal SQL output:
[image: Normal SQL output]

Stored Procedure output:
[image: Stored Procedure output]

Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`up_beta`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `usp_geo`(user_id bigint(20),latitude double(15,8),longitude double(15,8), dist int(100),location longtext,page int(2),page_size int(2))
BEGIN

    Declare limitStart int(10);

    Declare limitEnd int(10);


    SET @user_id=(SELECT user_id);

    set @gen=(select gender from users where user_id=@user_id);

    set @latitude = (SELECT latitude);

    set @longitude = (SELECT longitude);

    set @dist = (SELECT dist);

    SET @location=(SELECT location);

    set limitStart =  ((page*page_size)-page_size);

    set limitEnd =  page_size ;

    set @SNO = ((page - 1)*page_size);

    IF @gen='male' then
        set @gen='female';
    else
        set @gen='male';
    end if;


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE  if exists temp_tab;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tab(temp_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id bigint(20) unique,distance double(15,8) default NULL) CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT into temp_tab (user_id, distance)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT user_id, 6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS( @latitude )) * SIN(RADIANS(Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS( @latitude )) * COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude) - RADIANS( @longitude ))) AS `distance` FROM `user_log` WHERE user_id <>@user_id HAVING `distance` <= @dist ORDER BY `activity_at` DESC) as t1
GROUP BY user_id;



SELECT * FROM temp_tab;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE  if exists search_tab;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search_tab(temp_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id bigint(20) unique,name varchar(500),gender varchar(100),
    town longtext,current_location longtext default NULL,is_in_app tinyint(4) default 0,distance double(15,8)) CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO search_tab(user_id,name,gender,town,distance) 
SELECT a.user_id, a.name,a.gender,a.home_town,b.distance FROM users a, temp_tab b WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.gender=@gen AND a.relationship_id NOT IN(2,3,4);


 if @location<>'' AND @location<>NULL then
        begin
            set @city=(select concat('''','%',@location,'%',''''));

            set @gender =(select concat('''',@gen,''''));

           set @insert_sql = concat('INSERT IGNORE INTO search_tab(user_id,name,gender,town,location)
SELECT a.user_id, a.name,a.gender,a.home_town,b.current_location FROM users a, user_details b WHERE b.current_location LIKE ',@city,' AND a.id = b.user_id AND a.gender=',@gender,' AND a.relationship_id NOT IN(2,3,4)');

            PREPARE stmt1 FROM @insert_sql;
            EXECUTE stmt1;

        end;
 end if;


 update search_tab  set is_in_app=1 where user_fb_id in
    (select user_id from users where access_token is not null);



    select  @a:=@a+1 sno,user_id,name,gender,town,current_location,is_in_app,distance
    from search_tab ,(SELECT @a:= @SNO) AS a
    limit limitStart,limitEnd;

    select count(temp_id)as total_count from search_tab; 

end;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Where is the code? There's no "normal SQL" vs stored procedure. If you get different results it's because the code or the parameters are different

Comment: Also what database are you using? You used both the `mysql` and the `sql-server` tags. The code is invalid for SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I checked parameter and it was fine. to confirm i used the same inside the procedure. it throws 0 for distances. But the query gives correct output when it runs as raw sql.

Comment: And finally, why the temporary table if it's only used to return the same data as the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: it's impossible to help without the code. If everything was the same though, you'd get an answer. Post the stored procedure *and* the code that calls it. Otherwise you won't get any answers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry its mysql. Its only a part of the code. this portions is followed by few more lines of code. Since it throws the wrong output. it messes with the rest

Comment: BTW, your 1st screenshot shows an interesting user interface. Where is that from?

Comment: @SQLPolice Phpmyadmin

Comment: Please can you show how your stored procedure looks like?

Comment: @SQLPolice Sure . Just an min

Comment: @SQLPolice its updated